# CUDA 7.5 installation: Unsupported compiler error

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, ubuntu-15.10

I just tried installing CUDA 7.5 on my laptop. I disabled `lightdm` and did `sudo sh cuda7.5.run`. The driver installation passed but then I got an error `Unsupported compiler ...` and the installation fails. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: switch to a supported configuration.  Supported configurations are covered in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements).  If you are using ubuntu 15.10 (as your question is tagged), that is an unsupported configuration for CUDA 7.5

Comment: It is still possible to install CUDA on an unsupported configuration. Try to install gcc-4.8 and all the other required dependencies (like linux-headers etc.) Set gcc-4.8 as default compiler (something similar to the following  cd /usr/bin
  rm cc gcc c++ g++
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 cc
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 gcc
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/c++-4.8 c++
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++-4.8 g++
`). Then try to install again.

Comment: The issue is resolved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with `Ubuntu 15.10`. I installed `14.04` and could install CUDA. However, for my laptop there was a subtle point to mention. I had to install the NVIDIA driver via `System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers` and selecting the `tested` driver. Then I installed CUDA and answered `No` to driver installation bundled with CUDA installation file.

Answer (score 27):

I had a similar issue installing CUDA 7.5 in Ubuntu 16.04.

I've solved it using gcc/g++ 4.8 instead of 5.2.

You can install it and switch the default version using the command update-alternatives --install

For gcc 4.8 do:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 10
```

For g++ 4.8 do:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 10
```

Comment: for the g++, the first command line is wrong use `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8` instead.

Comment: Thanks @herve I've fixed the example for g++.

Comment: Worked for Cuda 9 in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to downgrade your gcc version.
For the people who want to keep their gcc version, I recommend you use the following way. 
http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/

Answer (score -2):

`sudo apt-get update` unity should also help